# Can we use E-mails instead of E-mail addresses?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is it correct to abbreviate **E-mail addresses** to **E-mails**?

Is one more formal than the other?

Comment: *e-mail* is now usually lowercase, and very often written without a hyphen as *email*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There seems to be some debate on this one, but I'd say that no, they are not the same thing, except sometimes.

An email, as CarSmack [suggests](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/36555/8727), generally refers to an email *message*, whereas an email address is a specific, well, email address.

That said, people very frequently refer to email addresses as emails.

> Yes, I have your email.

That, in almost every case, would mean I have your email address. I think I actually hear that more than I even hear "I have your email address." They're at least 50/50.

If I wanted to convey that I have an email message, I would say either of these:

> Yes, I *got* your email.
>   Yes, I have your email open.

In those cases, most if not all of the time, people will know you're talking about messages.

That said, just to add some extra confusion:

> You wrote down my email, right?
>   Yeah, I got it.

In that case, it could really mean either one. Either the asker is frivolously suggesting the recipient to copy an email down to paper, or they want to confirm that the other person wrote down their email address.

This is also present on many forms.

Take Outlook, even. Outlook is *probably* the most popular email client out there, and its contact management portion refers to addresses only as "email."

[image]

Nobody would read that and expect to copy in a full email message from someone.

So really, like many other caveats of the English language, it's just a matter of context. People virtually never say "email message" (I don't think I've ever heard that, actually), and call those "emails," but people can, based on context, refer either to addresses as "email addresses" or "emails." And I don't think it really has anything to do directly with formality. It might be more formal in some circumstances to make sure you're clear and avoid ambiguity, in which case "email address" might make more sense, but it's certainly nothing directly related to formality like, for instance, "y'all" versus "you all."

Comment: +1 Perhaps you have shown that email can be a short form for email address. As in: *I need your email.* But does the same hold true when talking about the plural? This was the form of the OP. So, can *I have/need your emails* ever mean *I have/need your email addresses.*?

Comment: Yep, I would take the pluralization as a contextual hint that we might be talking about messages, but it doesn't determine it either way. It's not *exactly* the same, but imagine "You have one of my emails, right?" I hear that from time to time, and it means addresses. And "I have so many emails" is completely ambiguous between meaning addresses and messages. Unfortunately I don't have *quite* as solid an argument on that as showing an Outlook screenshot for that, but I know I do hear people (myself included) say things like that from time to time.

Comment: @CarSmack Come to think of it, I can imagine a pollster saying "We collected 500 emails," where it would be fairly clear that they were referring to addresses and not messages.

Comment: This answer is definitely representative of actual usage. It's not all that dissimilar to how people use "phone" - Often at the checkout or ordering a pizza or what have you, they'll ask "can I get your phone". Surely I'm not handing a $800 phone over to some checkout clerk!

Comment: As a side note, if you're looking to use a fake email address, know that [there's a protocol for that](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#section-3).

Comment: @corsiKa You've got me there--it's not often people reference IETF standards to me :). Fixed.

Comment: It's very much context dependent. When my manager asks for the emails of everyone who did action X on day Y, he isn't asking me to do my best impression of the NSA.

Comment: @corsiKa: I don't think I've encountered that use of "phone". In the parts of the U.S. where I've lived, the usual shorthand for "phone number" is "number". (Which is interesting, come to think of it. The whole thing seems pretty arbitrary. I'm quite used to "cell" meaning "cell-phone number", but I would certainly do a double-take if someone asked me for my "home".)

Comment: @ruakh I've heard "phone" before, but yes "number" is much more common. "Phone," though, like "email," is pretty common on forms. Obviously that's a little different than general English, but it's something. Same with business cards. I can also imagine an interviewer saying something like "can I have your email and phone?" Again, definitely less common than "number," but it's still around. In fact, "home" would work there too. If you had a form with a header for "Phone Numbers," I can imagine "cell: " and "home: ." Different, but still somewhat relevant. Interesting.

Comment: I'm still not at all convinced that people use the plural emails when they mean email addresses. It sounds vaguely similar to softwares... :)  Maybe the people who say that say emails? And I've not heard, Can I get your phone? Wow!

Comment: @CarSmack no, I can assure you that I don't say software. "Emails" is certainly not an overwhelmingly common expression, but it definitely is one, whether technically grammatically correct or not. I can imagine it being a linguistic evolution from the singular "email" being used a lot, for what that's worth. I imagine that's what "phone" is, since people read it so often on forms, they've just started using it like that.

Comment: H3ll, my kids say *pause* instead of *time out* when playing backyard sports, so I get the "see it, say it" connection. And I wasn't implying that you say softwares. I guess I am just not ready to start saying emails. It goes against the grain of what I find acceptable. Last, mail is a mass noun, and I wonder how long, if ever, email was a mass noun. I never get mails in my snail mailbox. I get mailings, mail outs, and other junk. But don't tell me you get mails. :) And I never ask for someone's snail mail meaning their snail mail address. It's been a fun discussion.

Comment: @CarSmack Oh heavens, I said "I don't say software." You know what I mean. :P But yes, I agree, on all counts. "Emails" sounds pretty weird to me in most contexts as well, and I don't think there's any time "emails" sounds even marginally *better* than "email addresses," for what that's worth. Who knows. Language is weird, and English is weirder.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to know if it is correct to abbreviate **E-mail addresses** to **E-mails**. Is one more formal than the other?

**E-mail addresses** and **E-mails** are two different things.

E-mails refer to the individual mail messages that are written and sent via electronic means. Your inbox probably has e-mails in it.

This is different from e-mail addresses, which are the "electronic" addresses I need to send people one or more e-mails. Your address book probably has e-mail addresses in it.

Therefore, E-mails is **not** an abbreviation for E-mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is 100% (there are people that don't know better) but "Emails" in the plural is almost always referring to messages.  You would never tell a group of  people to "Give me your emails" if you wanted addresses.  In the singular it is ambiguous.  If you were telling them to fill ina form you might well say "include your email" but then it's clear from the context that address is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to an email address as an "email" is wrong in exactly the same way that referring to a telephone number as a "telephone" is wrong.

Comment: Except for the fact that the common abbreviation “number” (like in “here is my number”) exists but a corresponding counterpart “address” would be ambiguous in many contexts. But apart from that, a good analogy, since it actually carries the same nuances Matthew pointed out: there are forms with fields labeled “phone” and people know what that means from context. So +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using `emails` in all circumstances; using `email addresses`, while technically also correct, will come across as excessively precise.

That said, it is fine to use email *addresses* when you want to explicitly distinguish between those and email *messages*.

Comment: So, I have five emails for Sam can mean I have five email addresses for Sam?

Comment: I would normally interpret "I have five emails for Sam" as meaning that you have five messages intended for electronic delivery to Sam.